# Kio estas la esperanta vorto de "Doughnut"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Kio estas la esperanta vorto de "Doughnut"?

La vorto ne estas trovebla ĉe ReVo. Ankaŭ, ne ekzistas vikipedio paĝo pri tio.

Comment: Should you say 'de "doughnut"' or 'por "doughnut"'? Mi estas komencanto.

Answer (score 2):

La vortaro de John Wells sugestas la jenan:

> **doughnut** (ringa, bula) fritkuko, benjeto

*benjeto* estas proksima de la franca vorto *beignet*, sed eble *ringa fritkuko* estas pli memkomprenebla por nefrancparolantoj.

Parenteze, tiu ege utila vortaro estas facile aĉetebla kaj aĉetinda en [epub](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176), aŭ en papera formato de la [UEA](http://katalogo.uea.org/katalogo.php?inf=825).

Answer (score 2):

Once again, *national* food items do not have names in an *international* language. There is no word in Esperanto for doughnut.

That said, we discussed this at some length at NASK this year. Many people say ***benjeto*** which is a pastry similar to a doughnut. For years I have said ***pastoringo*** - which both describes a doughnut and is a partial translation of the national language name for a doughnut.

My preference is still for ***pastoringo*** but you will be in good company if you say ***benjeto*** -- not that anybody who hasn't been to NASK will know what you're talking about.

---

Pardonu. Mi ne rimarkis ke la originala demando estis en Esperanto. Jen traduko.

*Naciaj* manĝaĵoj ne havas nomojn en *internacia* lingvo. Ne estas vorto en Esperanto por doughnut.

Tion dirite, ni ja traktis tiun ĉi temon dum NASK ĉi-jare. Multaj diras ***benjeto*** kiu estas fritkuko simila al *doughnut*. Mi dum jaroj diras ***pastoringo***. Tio kaj priskribas la aferon kaj estas aludo al la nacilingva nomo por la afero.

Mi ankoraŭ preferas ***pastoringo*** sed ja eblas pravigi ***benjeto*** -- kvankam mi dubas ĉu la homoj kiuj ne venis al NASK komprenos la aferon sen rigardi en vortaro.

Comment: Estas multaj naciaj mangxajxoj kiuj havas nomojn en Esperanto. Mi opinias ke la unua frazo estas maltaugxa cxar gxi nek estas vera nek afable respondas al la demandinto.

Comment: **Pri vereco** - ja estas vere ke naciaj manĝaĵoj ne havas nomojn en internacia lingvo. Se iu esperantigas francan nomon kaj metas ĝin en PIV-on, tio ne nepre signifas ke tiu franca afero havas nomon en Esperanto. Cetere, se nacia afero fariĝas internacia, tio estas alia afero. Aferoj kiuj troviĝas nur en germanio, ekzemple, ne havas nomojn en la angla, kaj naciaj aferoj ne havas nomojn en internacia lingvo. **Pri afableco**, la vortoj "once again" estas signo de respekto al Lumo, kiu *instruas* Esperanton en YouTube - ke mi agnoskas ke li sekvas la aliajn diskutojn en SE.

Comment: Dankon pro la respondo. Eble mi uzos la vorto "Kukringo".

Comment: Q-kringo? Krome mi lernis ke en kelkaj partoj de usono estas grava distingo inter "powder doughnut" kaj "cake doughnut." Mi rekonas sed ne tre atentas la diferencon. Cetere, kiel oni diras fritter kaj kruller? :-)